# Ionic & azure mobile service atuhentication

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, azure-mobile-services

In my Phonegap/Ionic apps I am using azure mobile service authentication. It worked well.

```
$rootScope.mobileClient = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('...','...');
$rootScope.mobileClient.login('Google').then(
      function(){
        console.log('login successful!');
      },
      function(error){
        console.log(error);
      }
  );
```

But recently I tried to create a new app and the case is, that after the successful authentication with google, the popup does not close but redirects to "login/done#token=" instead. 
Usually this is a problem if you forget to add the two plugins, but I have done that:

```
cordova-plugin-device 1.0.2-dev "Device"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.0.2-dev "InAppBrowser"
```

I also tried the previous versions, that work in my older ionic projects, but no luck

```
org.apache.cordova.device 0.3.0 "Device"
org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser 0.3.3 "InAppBrowser"
```

It's driving me crazy :S

Comment: I believe this is an issue with Ionic and Mobile Services being used together. We have seen this in the past with push notifications.
Redirecting to login/done is the expected Mobile Services behavior, but that should close the browser window.
Are you able to get login working for a new App without Ionic?

Comment: yes I also believe this has to be an issue with Ionic and Mobile Services, but until recent updates to cordova, node.js and ionic (as suggested by ionic cli) this combination worked well. Could be a problem with plugins incopatibility or something, for starters it would be nice if someone could confirm having the same issue with the latest versions.
If I run it in the browser, it works ok, but obviously there are no plugins involved there.